# How to get most commented pages on your website?

Tags: facebook-fql

I am having a problem getting the most commented pages on my site. I wanted to return list of pages sorted by their comment count.

I have tried this one. But this is not efficient for me I have a lot of pages.

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, 
commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url IN ( "url", 
"url2") LIMIT 10
```

Are there other ways to get this?

Comment: Order BY comment_count desc ?

Comment: Hi I wanted to know if there are other ways to get the most commented pages in my domain aside from doing the query above wherein you have to provide the list of urls.

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways via the API to query the most commented pages on your website. If you have Insights integrated into your website you can make a close approximation.